# To Queue or Not to Queue

Tags: database-design, coding-style, logic, scheduled-tasks

I'm building an app to complete tasks on a weekly basis. Here is the basic logic:

```
Check datatable and look at timestamp
If timestamp is older than 1 week, complete task
Else skip
```

We see 2 ways of implementing this and would love your thoughts/opinion. Keep in mind, the database will grow exponentially, so database performance is a real concern. We will add rough

1. We could create a script that runs weekly (or daily), checks the database, and if it finds an item that is TRUE, it adds a database record to a Queue table. Later we run the actual tasks off of the Queue table until it's empty.
2. Create a loop statement to check the datatable and process each row that is TRUE.

Thanks!

Comment: With the right index, getting the records to be executed should be quick enough. For instance, if the table has a "STATUS" field and a "NEXT_FIRE_TIME" field, and an index that has these two at the start, then selecting the rows you need should not be much slower than reading from a separate table. And, it will mean one less step/element to deal with. 

Also, what language will you use to code? You might find a ready-made tool that does some of the storing / checking / firing for you (e.g. Quartz if you're using Java)

Comment: Do you have a maintenance window? You said performance is a factor... if possible you should schedule this off hours during your maintenance window. Option 2 will create unnecessary load on the server (potentially during peak hours). If this processing can wait 7 days.. it can probably wait a few more hours. ;)